# Cosine interpolation reverts to linear interpolation in higher dimensions?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric, interpolation

[Paul Bourke's article on interpolation](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) explains different types of interpolation including linear, cubic, Hermite spline and cosine.  He goes on to state (emphasis mine):

> In most cases the interpolation can be extended into higher dimensions simply by applying it to each of the x,y,z coordinates independently. This is shown on the right for 3 dimensions for all but the cosine interpolation. **By a cute trick the cosine interpolation reverts to linear if applied independently to each coordinate.**

I've implemented all of them in 2D and realized the truth in this.  When I interpolate between 2D points by linearly interpolating X and cosine interpolating Y the output is curvy; however, if I interpolate both X and Y independently by cosine, it *does* revert to being a linear interpolation.

Looking at the equations, I guess it should be something to do with the same parameter `t` being used for both the equations, that makes this

$$
    x(t) = x_1 + ((1 - \cos({t \pi})) / 2) (x_2 - x_1)  \\
    y(t) = y_1 + ((1 - \cos({t \pi})) / 2) (y_2 - y_1)
$$

into

$$
    x(t) = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1)  \\
    y(t) = y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1)
$$

I'm really interested in knowing what "cute trick" makes cosine interpolation linear.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please refer me to a source where I can find proof for cosine interpolation formula $ x(t) = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1) ,  y(t) = y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first of equations does not magically transform into the second set via some "cute trick".

But, from the first set of equations, you get:
$$
\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{y-y_1}{y_2-y_1}
$$
which is obviously the equation of a straight line, $L$.

The first and second sets of equations both describe the same line, $L$, but, depending on which equations you use, the line is transversed by the point $(x(t), y(t))$ at different speeds.

Check the point at $t=\tfrac14$ using both sets of equations. Both equations will give you a point lying on the line $L$, but it won't be the same point.

Cosine interpolation gives you a linear shape, but not linear motion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I sort of convinced myself with this: _it's a convex combination of two points, so it can only give a line_. In 1D, we're really just plotting the cosine curve so we get a non-linear output; in that case writing it parametrically, it'd be $x(t) = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1); y(t) = y_1 + ((1 - \cos{t\pi})/2)(y_2 - y_1)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree that velocity will be different but the shape would be the same. Your last statement is a really nice way of putting it :)

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive, and also rigorous way, to figure out the answer to your question is the 
[Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).

Given 
$$
x = A\cos \left( {at + \delta } \right)\quad y = B\cos \left( {bt} \right)
$$
when $a/b=1$ and $\delta =0$ you get a line.